# pgfgantt not working with babel

Tags: babel, pgfgantt

In this example month names are printed in English even the babel package is loaded with French language.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
%\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{lscape}


 \begin{document}
     \begin{landscape}
         \begin{tikzpicture} % optional
            \begin{ganttchart}[x unit=2.5mm, time slot format=isodate]{2014-04-28}{2014-07-11}
                \gantttitlecalendar{month=name} \\
                 \ganttbar{Task 1}{2014-04-28}{2014-05-10} \\
             \end{ganttchart}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Babel is not working with pgfgantt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
\usepackage[frenchb]{translator}
```

before loading the `pgfgantt` package.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[frenchb]{translator}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{ganttchart}[x unit=2mm, time slot format=isodate]{2014-06-20}{2014-09-11}
      \gantttitlecalendar{month=name} \\
      \ganttbar{Task 1}{2014-07-28}{2014-08-10} \\
    \end{ganttchart}
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, they don't tell that in `pgfgantt` manual and searching Google didn't help me.

Comment: Does not work for me. Copying the MWE from the answer results in English month names. Using TeXLive 2014 and `pgfgantt` version 4.