# Passing options to loaded package not working with Beamer class

Tags: beamer, option-clash, translator

I have this :

```
\documentclass[translator={frenchb}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\PassOptionsToPackage{frenchb}{translator}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{tikz}


%\usepackage{concrete}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\uselanguage{French}
\languagepath{French}

 \scalebox{.42}{
\begin{tikzpicture} % optional
   \begin{ganttchart}[x unit=2.2mm, 
                      y unit chart=1.2cm, 
                      time slot format=isodate, 
                     ]
                      {2014-04-14}{2014-07-11}
   \gantttitlecalendar{month=name} \\      
   \end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I can't mange to print the month names in French. Normally I have just to load `translator` package with the `frenchb` option (look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173750/pgfgantt-not-working-with-babel#answer-173756)). This package is already loaded by beamer so I tried `\PassOptionsToPackage{frenchb}{translator}` but it's not working. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\PassOptionsToPackage` has to be used *before* the package is loaded:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{frenchb}{translator}
\documentclass{beamer}
```

Or `frenchb` can be given as global option:

```
\documentclass[frenchb]{beamer}
```

Comment: Was just writing the same, but I'd use just `french` :-)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that I can put commands before `\documentclass`!