# Changing language of weeks and months in pgfgantt

Tags: languages, pgfgantt

I am using the `pgfgantt` package in a project that is supposed to be written in Swedish and I'm having trouble changing the names of months. I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173750/pgfgantt-not-working-with-babel?newreg=aebca6e11da546318f9536617a06af45) and tried using `\usepackage[swedish]{translator}` before `\usepackage{pgfgantt}`but the language is still in English.

I am using Sharelatex with the PdfLaTeX compiler.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please, always add an MWE, showing, what you have already tried.  It helps us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`translator` is not enough, you also need to load `babel`. Language name can be introduced as a documentclass option and it will be applied to both `babel` and `translator`.

Note: As I don't have Swedish translator dictionary, the example uses Spanish.

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,
vgrid,
x unit=18mm,
time slot format=little-endian
]{7.1.2013}{13.1.2013}
\gantttitlecalendar*{7.1.2013}{13.1.2013}{
month, month=name, month=shortname, weekday,
weekday=name, weekday=shortname
}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

As it seems that Swedish dictionaries doesn't officially exist for `translator`, you will have to provide corresponding translations in your source file:

```
\documentclass[Swedish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\uselanguage{Swedish}
\languagepath{Swedish}
\providetranslation[to=Swedish]{January}{Januari}
\providetranslation[to=Swedish]{Monday}{Måndag}
%---- Complete with missing months and days

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,
vgrid,
x unit=18mm,
time slot format=little-endian
]{7.1.2013}{13.1.2013}
\gantttitlecalendar*{7.1.2013}{13.1.2013}{
month, month=name, month=shortname, weekday,
weekday=name, weekday=shortname
}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I might have been unclear in my question. I am using `babel` and it's still not working.

Comment: @HankyP   I don't see a Swedish [dict files in CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/translator) for translator, so it won't work on ShareLaTeX

Comment: @HankyP Answer updated with a provisional solution tested on Sharelatex